# VBA getPixel always returns -1

Tags: vba, excel, gdi, userform

I'm trying to load a picture into excel and extract its pixels' RGB value into a 2D array.

However, When I try to use the GetPixel function, it always returns -1. I made sure it has loaded the picture onto a userform, but still returns -1.

Here's my code:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetPixel Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As LongPtr, ByVal x As Long, ByVal Y As Long) As Long


Dim color As Long
UserForm1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\1.bmp")
Debug.Print (UserForm1.Image1.Picture)
Debug.Print (GetPixel(UserForm1.Image1.Picture.Handle, 100, 100))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getPixel` function isn't compatible with `loadPicture`.

My solution was to load the picture onto a visible userform, then extract the pixels of the userform.